# Terminology for ownership

Tags: legal-terms

Let us assume an improvement (wooden deck) has been made on a Florida condominium by an individual owner (not the Association) **on the common area**.   There is debate as to whether the owner actually had the proper approvals.  The owner has sold the condo to a new owner.

My question is: what is the simple/effective terminology for the **new** owner that did not build the deck, so as to differentiate him from the owner-builder?

Comment: @downvote: Please provide constructive comment / feedback so I may improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

Either "Owner" or "Association Member" would be the simplest and most effective terminology to describe a resident owner of one of the condominiums within your group.

Whether or not the person who previously resided there made some improvement to a common area, (authorized or not) has no bearing or relevance on the legal status, or any name/title used to describe the current resident.

If any legal action arises out of the situation the previous owner may be referred to as "the defendant"...

Ownership of the common areas should be spelled out in your association agreements, what do they say?